# com.vaadin.flow.router.NotFoundException: No route found for the given navigation target

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am currently using vaadin v23.
I want to navigate to (change view / page) to "Dashboard"

Default - login page view code looks like this:

```
package com.fd.jvmbackend.views.adminPanel.login

import com.fd.jvmbackend.extensions.isNull
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.AdminPanelRoute
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.BaseView
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.Extras
import com.vaadin.flow.component.AttachEvent
import com.vaadin.flow.component.DetachEvent
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Text
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Unit
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification
import com.vaadin.flow.router.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


@Route(value = AdminPanelRoute.LOGIN)
@PageTitle("Login | FD CMS")
class LoginView() : BaseView() {

    private val TAG = "LoginView"

    private var viewModel: LoginViewModel? = null

    override fun onAttach(attachEvent: AttachEvent?) {
        super.onAttach(attachEvent)

        viewModel = LoginViewModel()

        val label = Label("Welcome.")

        val loginField = getLoginTextField("Login", "ex: mike", true, true)
        val passwordField = getPasswordField("Password", "ex. myLongPassword", true, true, true)

        val button = Button("Log in with credentials")
        button.setWidth(15F, Unit.PERCENTAGE)
        button.addClickListener { event ->
            viewModel?.onLoginClicked(loginField.value, passwordField.value)
        }

        add(label)
        add(loginField)
        add(passwordField)

        add(button)

        collectorsJob = lifecycleScope.launch {

            launch {
                viewModel?.getPageTitle()?.collect { value ->
                    println("$TAG -> getPageTitle -> ${value}")
                    ui.get().access {
                        ui.get().page.setTitle(value)
                    }
                }
            }

            launch {
                viewModel?.getErrorText()?.collect { value ->
                    if(value.isNull()){
                        return@collect
                    }

                    ui.get().access {
                        notification?.close()
                        notification = Notification.show(value,TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5).toInt(),Notification.Position.BOTTOM_CENTER)
                    }

                }
            }


            launch {
                viewModel?.getIsLoading()?.collect { value ->
                    ui.get().access {
                        if (value) {
                            progressDialog = getIndeterminateProgressDialog("Loading", "please wait")
                            progressDialog?.open()
                        } else {
                            progressDialog?.close()
                            progressDialog = null
                        }
                    }

                    ui.get().access {
                        loginField.isEnabled = !value
                    }

                    ui.get().access {
                        passwordField.isEnabled = !value
                    }

                    ui.get().access {
                        button.isEnabled = !value
                    }

                }
            }

            launch {
                viewModel?.getNavigationRouterLink()?.collect { value ->

                    if(value.isNull()){
                        return@collect
                    }

                    ui.get().access {
                        ui.get().navigate(
                            DashboardView::class.java,
                            RouteParameters(Extras.USER_ID, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10))
                        )
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onDetach(detachEvent: DetachEvent?) {
        viewModel?.onCleared()
        viewModel = null
        super.onDetach(detachEvent)
    }
}
```

AdminPanelRoute.LOGIN = "login",
AdminPanelRoute.DASHBOARD = "dashboard"

Code which handles navigating to another page/view looks like this:

```
ui.get().navigate(DashboardView::class.java, RouteParameters(Extras.USER_ID, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10)))
```

After execution this is what I get:

> Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.router.NotFoundException: No route found
> for the given navigation target
> 'com.fd.jvmbackend.views.adminPanel.login.DashboardView' and
> parameters '{extra_user_id=ElKbspkysb}'

DashboardView.kt contents:

```
package com.fd.jvmbackend.views.adminPanel.login

import com.fd.jvmbackend.util.ResourceHandler
import com.fd.jvmbackend.views.AdminPanelRoute
import com.vaadin.flow.component.AttachEvent
import com.vaadin.flow.component.DetachEvent
import com.vaadin.flow.component.applayout.AppLayout
import com.vaadin.flow.component.applayout.DrawerToggle
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route


@Route(value = AdminPanelRoute.DASHBOARD)
@PageTitle("Dashboard | FD CMS")
class DashboardView:AppLayout() {

    private val TAG = "DashboardView"

    val label = Label("Secret message -> ")

    override fun onAttach(attachEvent: AttachEvent?) {
        super.onAttach(attachEvent)

    }

    override fun onDetach(detachEvent: DetachEvent?) {
        super.onDetach(detachEvent)
    }
}
```

Please tell me where is the mistake. What am I doing wrong ? The view -> DashboardView is registered with @Route annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `DashboardView::class.java` is interpreted as the literal Java String `"com.fd.jvmbackend.views.adminPanel.login.DashboardView"`, not the class object, and the wrong overload of `ui.navigate` is called. Try passing the Route String (`AdminPanelRoute.DASHBOARD`) instead.

EDIT: I note you're also passing route parameters with the second parameter of `navigate`. DashboardView doesn't accept route parameters, so you should remove those.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation is paramater sensitiv. That means if you navigate to the dashboard Route with Parameters it will not be found. Remove the argument from your `UI.navigate` expression or declare your `@Route` with a value like "dashboard/:id". See the [URL Template Docu](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/routing/templates).